# Python DFS Shortest Path Search with weighted, undirected graph

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I'm having trouble parsing through this graph dictionary:

```
routes = {'a': [('b', 5.0), ('c', 8.0)], 'c': [('a', 8.0), ('d', 2.0)], 
'b' [('a', 5.0), ('d', 6.0)], 'e': [('d', 12.0), ('g', 3.0)], 
'd':  [('b', 6.0),('c', 2.0), ('e', 12.0), ('f', 2.0)], 'g': [('e', 3.0),
('f', 7.0)],'f': [('d',2.0), ('g', 7.0)]}
```

How do I separate out the values of each edge while running the dictionary through a DFS Search looking at 2 keys? I'm not very familiar with dict.

So far I have,

```
def dfs(graph, start, end, path):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end: 
        paths.append(path)
    for node in graph.childrenOf(start):
        if node not in path:
            dfs(graph, node, end, path)
```

I need to return the smallest weighted path, so I need the numbers in the values separated out and summed as the program runs.

Comment: What part exactly of the dictionary you want? Keys, values or part of the values (which parts)?

Comment: Keys are the colon left side stuff and the right side stuff are, you guessed, the values

Comment: I need to return the smallest weighted path, so I need the numbers in the values separated out and summed as the program runs.

Comment: `defaultdict(dict)` is convenient.  If you need something faster, there are other data structures which may be slightly less convenient but much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your graph using a dict of dicts:

```
routes = {'a': {'b': 5.0, 'c': 8.0}, 'c': {'a': 8.0, 'd': 2.0}}
```

Then `routes['a']['b']` will return the weight, which is `5.0` in this case. If you need to get all the children of a node you can do `routes['a'].keys()` and that will return `['c', 'b']`.

Answer (score 0):

`routes` is your graph, in adjacency-list format. Each key is a node, the value being a list of `(other_node, edge_weight)` tuples. So what you're looking for is how "graph.childrenOf" should work.

Assuming `start, end` are simple string node names (like `'a'`) you can just look them up in the dictionary; e.g. `graph[a]` will give you `[('b', 5.0), ('c', 8.0)]`. You can iterate directly over both the node and weight using python's nifty built-in tuple unpacking, like so:

```
# replace your for loop with this:
for node, weight in graph[start]:
```